# Chrome Extension: Overriding CSS Class Property Styles + Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I'm facing an issue where I need to override the style properties of a CSS class itself, not just the individual elements with that class. Specifically, I want to modify properties like background-color of a specific CSS class in the page's styles.

My use case involves dynamically changing the appearance of elements on web pages that use a particular CSS class. However, it's important to note that I don't want to apply styles to each individual element with that class, but to the class definition itself.

I've tried several approaches, including using JavaScript to add new styles to the class and using the MutationObserver and Intersection Observer APIs to monitor for changes, but these approaches haven't worked as expected.

I'm looking for guidance on how to programmatically target and modify the style properties of a CSS class defined in the page's styles from a Chrome extension. If there's a specific Chrome extension API or approach that can help with this, I'd greatly appreciate any insights or code examples to achieve this.

example:
I load page x/page/
this page has it's own .css styles (which have a dynamic name, and are often unloaded after being injected)
one of the css class applied is for example ._blablabla and has background-color #00000
I want to change the background-color of ._blablabla to red, so even if new elements are dynamically loaded, they use the modified class which will have the red color.

I have tried editing the elements theirself but my approach is failing because they are dynamically loaded by scrolling and every approach I tried by adding listeners didn't work and I don't want to loop all the time to detect the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

MutationObserver should work just fine. Use mutation.type === "childList" to observe new dynamic element.

CSS is cascading, which means you should change inline style of target element directly for highest priority.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).